# x and y get added additional value after setting Transform()

Tags: snap.svg

I am working on svg free transform. Everything works fine except if the object has its own transform attribute with scale value after page initialed.

Something like this:

```
<g transform="matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,70,70)"></g>
```

Here is what I do to dragging and resizing this object

```
var newTransform = 't' + (this.data('xy').x) + ',' + (this.data('xy').y);
                newTransform += 'r' + (this.data('r'))
                newTransform += 's' + (this.data('s'))

this.transform(newTransform);
```

If the object has no initial scale value, this works fine as except. The object can be dragged and scaled perfectly.

But, if the object has scale attribute(not equal to 1) at the beginning, when I set the first transform(), the object will be scaled again. Additional x,y and size will be added. If I use matrix instead, the problem can be solved. But the object won't scale from center.

Transform with matrix:

```
   var t = new Snap.Matrix()
   t.add(this.data('s'),0,0,this.data('s'),this.data('xy').x,this.data('xy').y);
   this.transform(t);
```

Am I doing something wrong on transform with snap svg string? How do I prevent from scale twice for the first transform(str)?

Comment: It would be useful to put an example on a jsfiddle, and explain. What isn't clear is, if it has a scale of 2 already and the freetransform scales 2, why wouldn't you want it be scaled 4 ? Often what I would do, is something like, this.transform( this.transform() + myNewTransform ); so it includes the original transform everytime, and myNewTransform created from the control handles.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/jbvc1rhe/1/ . I wish the transform attribute can be overwrote not "plus". I tried either ways in demo and got different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can get quite complex. The simplest way if it can be incorporated, is to place the element to drag inside a g/group element. Then place the drag on that outer g/group element.

This keeps the existing transformation on the inner element in place, and doesn't get messy. So if you can include an extra group element into the svg, I would go this route.

If you can't for whatever reason. I think longer term (especially if you will be doing a freetransform including dynamic rotations etc), then I think you need to get a lot more complicated. I'm including a starting route I would possibly use, that will also be able to cope with a scaled viewbox/screen as well, as this introduces extra complexity.

So I would possibly introduce a couple of new methods...

getCursorPoint gets a real point of a mouse, accounting for any transformations on the screen (as opposed to the element). I'm not sure you need this in your specific example yet, but you may find you hit this problem later with a zoomed in paper or something.

getTransformedDrag, accounts for any screen transformations when dragging.

```
Element.prototype.getCursorPoint = function( x, y ) {
    var pt = this.paper.node.createSVGPoint();      
    pt.x = x; pt.y = y;
    return pt.matrixTransform( this.paper.node.getScreenCTM().inverse() ); 
}

Element.prototype.getTransformedDrag = function( otx, oty, x, y ) {
    var xy = this.getCursorPoint( x, y );
    var tdx = {};
    var snapInvMatrix = this.data('origTransform').invert();

    snapInvMatrix.e = snapInvMatrix.f = 0;

    tdx.x = snapInvMatrix.x( xy.x - otx, xy.y - oty );
    tdx.y = snapInvMatrix.y( xy.x - otx, xy.y - oty );
    return tdx;
}
```

Now we've got a bit of background fluff around dragging out of the way, we can plug those in to some element dragging....

Store the possibly screen transformed cursor positions and the initial matrix on the element.

```
var dragStart = function(x, y, ev) {
    this.data('origTransform', this.transform().localMatrix)
    var txy = this.getCursorPoint(x,y)
    this.data('oxy', {x: txy.x, y: txy.y });
}

var dragMove = function(dx, dy, x, y, ev) {
    var tdr = this.getTransformedDrag( this.data('oxy').x, this.data('oxy').y, x, y)
    this.data('xy', {
            x: tdr.x,
            y: tdr.y
        })
    .updateTransform();
}

Element.prototype.updateTransform = function() {
    var newTransform = 't' + (this.data('xy').x) + ',' + (this.data('xy').y);
    //newTransform += 'r' + (this.data('r'))
    //newTransform += 's' + (this.data('s'))
    this.transform(this.data('origTransform').toTransformString() + newTransform )

    return this;
}
```

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbvc1rhe/11/)

As mentioned, this may seem overly complex, but I'm just trying to include some extra code you may find useful later, as it's quite a complex area. So just use this as a reference when you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, it's a little bit complex. I am not sure whether this solve my problem. I think I have take time to read this more detail. If I remove scale 's' data from my code, it works find too. The problem is when I apply this.transform(str), the element gets scaled again. I have solved drag in viewport problem already. I just need to know how to overwrote transform attribute without scale twice. The major problem is scale.(I haven't tested rotate yeah )

Comment: Note, I've also updated a while back a Snap free transform plugin (originally for raph) at https://github.com/ibrierley/Snap.svg.FreeTransform/  (dev branch may be more useful atm), that could help with some problems, if only to look at.

Comment: Yes, that is really nice free transform plugin, I love it. I'm developing a free transform tool with slider bar. That makes transform behavior a little bit easier and gets better performance. So, I really need to take time to see how to take your code as reference to solve my problem. Adding a new g is a good idea, I will also keeping trying to see if there any other trick to replace transform attribute directly. If you have any other new idea about this, please let me know. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Since I've mark this as correct answer. May I keep asking related question here if I find some new stuffs? Is that better for start a new topic?

Comment: If it's a separate question, I would ask a new one and include example code. If it's relating to the code above, feel free to ask, or you can contact me at github or svg.dabbles.info if it's relating to the freetransform plugin.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I  think there is no simple way to replace transform directly with this.transform(str). I found that this.transform(str) ignores element current scale center point. It moves to current x,y as center point and re-scales it. Is there any method to set scale center point(x,y)? I am also trying to add element inside <g>. I got small question here. I'll dynamically create <g> for the image once I click the image. After editing, the data needs to be saved. How do I combine <g> transform attribute with the image's?
 https://jsfiddle.net/jbvc1rhe/12/

Comment: If you use a Snap transform string, scale will scale using the center of the element to scale from. Otherwise you can specify an x,y as parameters 3,4 of scale command. Eg 's2,2,100,200' will scale with 100,200 as center point. For the other question, you could possibly look at el.transform().globalMatrix or diffMatrix